# How do I design a pattern that only captures strings without certain character combinations?

Tags: php, regex

I'm struggling with regex lookaheads and all the tutorials I can find are for password checks and not for certain character combinations.

Here's a problem I don't understand which describes my struggle with this part of regex:

```
$string1 = 'I have a yellow engine, I have a black engine';
$string2 = 'I have a yellow engine, I have a red engine';
$string3 = 'I have a red engine, I have a black engine';

$pattern = '~I.*?(?!.*(red|green|blue)).*?engine~';

$preg_match_all($pattern, $string[1-3], $matches);
```

`$string1` matches correctly:

```
0 => "I have a yellow engine"
1 => "I have a black engine"
```

`$string2` matches the entire string and `$string3` matches similar to `$string1`.

How do I design a pattern that only captures strings ('I have a [colour] engine') without certain colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` after your negative look-ahead will match everything and actually will destroy the effect of the look-ahead. You can simply use following regex:

```
I\s(?:(?!(red|green|blue)).)*engine
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tO9nC5/1

Note that you even don't need `.*` inside the look-ahead, because you have a `*` out of it which makes it to match every length of string.

Also note that if you want to prevent your regex to match strings like following:

```
I have everything I don't engine
```

In fact if you want to match the inner `I` before `engine` you better to add `I` to the list of forbidden words:

```
I\s(?:(?!(I|red|green|blue)).)*engine
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Nothing I tried got me anywhere for several hours, but this definitely points me in a promising direction and regex101 looks like a marvelous tool.